# Scrapy Piplines deal with data

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to write a crawler with scrapy, after I have written the crawler file, item file, piplines file, etc. I want to save the data into the database, but I find that the data type of item['url'] is actually string type, the string contains the list, I cannot get the data inside, and I don't find where the problem is.

```
import pymysql
from . import settings


class JumiaspiderPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.conn=pymysql.connect(
        host=settings.MYSQL_HOST,
        db=settings.MYSQL_DBNAME,
        user=settings.MYSQL_USER,
        passwd=settings.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=False
    )
    self.cursor=self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.insertdata(item)
    return item

def insertdata(self,item):
    sql="insert into jumia_scrapy (url) values (" +item['url']+")"
    print(sql)
    print(type(item['url'])
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
    self.conn.commit()
```

Why is `item['url']` of type str? I couldn't get list data.

Comment: why shouldn't it be of type `str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the url in your item parsing function as following.

```
item["url"] = response.url
```

Comment: sorry, I want to get url that matches regularly, I already get url after use eval function, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simpler Pipeline like SQLAlchemy or dataset which is based on SQLAlchemy.

example with dataset: 
[SQLAlchemy/dataset how to specify created table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098332/sqlalchemy-dataset-how-to-specify-created-table)

Comment: thanks, I already get the answer. use sqlalchemy is good advice, I will try to it, thanks again.